# How can I access to my app with WildFly

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm having a very painful time with WildFly.

I successfully deployed my war and the log said

```
WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /myapp
```

And I can't access the app with 404.

```
http://192.168.56.101:8080/myapp/index.html
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure, you have an index.html at the right place in your war-file? You must probably post more information on your file structure, web.xml, etc.

Another stumbling block could be in standalone.xml (config file of wildfly): To which IP is the application server bound? 127.0.0.1? Or 0.0.0.0?
Try accessing the app with http://localhost:8080/... (on the machine you deployed it). If this works, you need to change your standalone.xml file (replace all '127.0.0.1' occurrences with '0.0.0.0' is the easiest way)

Hope this helps. Otherwise, try to be more specific.